# How can I use a vector to label my x axis using imagesc?

Tags: matlab, axis

I am plotting ceilometer data using an adapted version of the imagesc function.
However, I would like to use time as labels for the X-axis.

```
a=find(Ceilo_Time >14 & Ceilo_Time <15);
Ceilo_14=Ceilo_Time(a);
Ceilo_Min=(Ceilo_14-14)*60;
Time_Ceilo=Ceilo_Min/100 %seconds after 14.00
Ceilo_Bs_cut=Ceilo_Bs2(:,a);

imagesc_ceilo( Ceilo_Bs_cut, 5,Time_Ceilo);
```

I would like to use some values of Time_Ceilo for the scale of the x axis which is labelled UTM time...

I would also like to add a red vertical bar at a certain time.

Can someone help ?

Thnx